# SSH keeps asking for password in spite of authorized_key

Tags: ssh

I created such a key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my key to go to X" -f ~/.ssh/keyname
```

Then added this to my `.ssh/config`

```
# Name
Host name login.name.com
User USERNAMEHERE
Hostname login.name.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyname
PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
Port 8001
ServerAliveInterval 120
ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

I put `keyname.pub` in the remote's `.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
...    
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZD...XxQlAX my key to go to X
```

with on remote: `chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys` and `chmod 700 .ssh`

Now I still get asked for USERNAMEHERE's password... logs to `ssh -vvv name` (which I can't decrypt) :

```
╍ᗇ ssh -vvv name
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myname/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/myname/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/myname/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for name
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to login.name.com port 8002.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/name type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/myname/.ssh/name-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to login.name.com:8002 as 'USERNAMEHERE'
debug3: put_host_port: [login.name.com]:8002
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:84
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [login.name.com]:8002
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:epXBPgPUxN859nWsyfeOA9ie8dFezoed7d1dsHtdDCk
debug3: put_host_port: [69.28.236.4]:8002
debug3: put_host_port: [login.name.com]:8002
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:84
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [login.name.com]:8002
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:77
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [69.28.236.4]:8002
debug1: Host '[login.name.com]:8002' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:84
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/myname/.ssh/name (0x7f93396034b0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
USERNAMEHERE@login.name.com's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong key file. The log shows this:

```
debug2: key: /Users/myname/.ssh/name (0x7f93396034b0), explicit
```

but you specified ~/.ssh/keyname in your .ssh/config file.

Comment: but it's the same location

Comment: Log shows ssh is looking for the private key:
    `.ssh/name`
but your .ssh/config file uses:
    `.ssh/keyname`
So one of them is wrong.